# regular expression for matching NOT finding a word, and then finding another

Tags: regex

I can't seem to figure out what reg. expr. notation fits my needs:

I have wrapped some debugging code in DEBUG() macros...

so for example to print some debug output in log level 1 i use the following bits of code:

```
DEBUG_LVL_1(printf("some text");)
```

This is not always and everywhere the case though - sometimes I have the printf statements without a macro wrapper.
I want to do a search and replace for those case... i.e. where there is NO DEBUG_LVL_ macro , but there exist a printf statement...

how do I do that?

Comment: All `printf` without `DEBUG_LVL_`: `grep -r printf * | grep -v DEBUG_LVL_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lookaheads are supported in your language/tool of choice you can use

```
^(?!.*DEBUG_LVL_1).*printf
```

`(?!^.*DEBUG_LVL_1)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), this will fail if `DEBUG_LVL_1` is found somewhere in the string.

So this regex will match `printf`, but only if there is no `DEBUG_LVL_1` somewhere in the same row.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?315dr)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go `^((?!DEBUG_LVL_1)printf.*)$` And by the way, use this site http://rubular.com in order to check your regexps